# Why's the formdata coming back as empty object and POST request giving me an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure why `console.log(formData);` displays an empty (`FormData {}`) when checking the console, despite `console.log(data);` displaying the correct data.

Also, when I do a `POST` request, I get an error that says `Missing boundary in multipart/form-data POST`.  I checked on SO and I see multiple places that say that I should put `headers:{content-type: undefined}` in the `headers` but that didn't do the trick.

I believe you need to use `FormData` to send a file via POST request.  How can I successfully send the file being uploaded via a POST request?

**Note:** The API works with Postman, so we can rule out that API's the problem,

JS code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {Button, Image, Modal} from "react-bootstrap";

const Gallery = () => {

    const [filePreview, setFilePreview] = useState(null);

    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);

    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const handleFileInput = (e) => {
        setFilePreview(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0]);
    }

    const uploadFile = () => {

       var formData = new FormData();
       formData.append("userUpload",selectedFile);

       console.log(formData);

        const data = {
            'userUpload': selectedFile
        }

        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        }

        console.log(data);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8005/api/file-upload', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

    return (
        <form encType="multipart/form-data">
            <div className="fileUpload text-center">
                <input type="file" onChange={handleFileInput} name="userUpload" required/>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                    Launch demo modal
                </Button>
            </div>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <Image fluid src={filePreview}/>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => uploadFile()}>Upload!</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>

        </form>
    );
}

export default Gallery;
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't you post `formData` rather than `data`?

Comment: @Patrick yeah, I'd assume that  I should post `formData` but the variable's logging an empty  object for some odd reason.

Comment: Logging a `FormData` instance will always result in an empty object because of how FormData objects work. You can loop over the object to see if there are any values in the object. `for (const [key, value] of formData) { console.log(key, value) `}

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Interesting!  Thanks, Emiel.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: As Emiel points out logging a FormData instance will not print the items. You can try to do `console.log([...formData.entries()])` instead to see what the item contains.